# room error : The columns returned by the query does not have the fields

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

> error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields
>   [primaryKey,ID,entradaId,encounterId,JobTypeID,IsStat,localFlags,State,OwnerDictatorID,QueueID,audioUploadState,imagesUploadState,hasDictation,hasImages,hasChatUpload,jobState,referringPhysicianId,StatusGroupID,jobRhythmWorkFlowId,rhythmRecordingDetaion,isRhythmJob,isSendToTranscriptionEnabled]
>   in com.entradahealth.entrada.core.domain.Job even though they are
>   annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: []
>       Job writeJob(long ID, long EntradaID, long EncounterID, long jobTypeID, boolean Stat, int

```
 @Query("UPDATE Jobs SET ID = :ID, EntradaID = :EntradaID, EncounterID = :EncounterID, " +
        "jobTypeID = :jobTypeID, Stat = :Stat, LocalFlags = :LocalFlags, State = :State, " +
        "AudioUploadState = :AudioUploadState, HasDictation = :HasDictation, HasImages = " +
        ":HasImages, HasChatUpload = :HasChatUpload, ImagesUploadState = :ImagesUploadState, " +
        "UpdatedDateInUTC = :UpdatedDateInUTC, MessageThreadID = :MessageThreadID, " +
        "lastsynctime = :lastsynctime, referringphysicianid = :referringphysicianid, QueueID =" +
        " :QueueID, dictationtext = :dictationtext, jobstatusgroup = :jobstatusgroup, " +
        "uploadeddate = :uploadeddate, RhythmTagMetadata = :RhythmTagMetadata, RhythmWorkFlowId = " +
        ":RhythmWorkFlowId, RhythmRecordedDuration = :RhythmRecordedDuration, IsRhythmJob =" +
        " :IsRhythmJob, lastvisitedtagposition = :lastvisitedtagposition WHERE ID = :ID")
Job writeJob(long ID, long EntradaID, long EncounterID, long jobTypeID, boolean Stat, int
        LocalFlags, int State, int AudioUploadState, boolean HasDictation, boolean HasImages,
             boolean HasChatUpload, int ImagesUploadState, String UpdatedDateInUTC, String MessageThreadID,
             String lastsynctime, long referringphysicianid, long QueueID, String dictationtext,
             int jobstatusgroup, String uploadeddate, String RhythmTagMetadata, long RhythmWorkFlowId,
             long RhythmRecordedDuration, boolean IsRhythmJob, String lastvisitedtagposition);







@Entity(tableName = "jobs")
public class Job implements Parcelable
{
    //Need one field in the table to be primary key(unused )
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "primaryKey")
    private long primaryKey;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    @JsonIgnore
    public long ID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "EntradaID")
    @JsonProperty(FIELD_JOB_ID)
    public long entradaId;

    @Ignore
    @JsonProperty(FIELD_JOB_NUMBER)
    public String number;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "EncounterID")
    @JsonProperty(Encounter.FIELD_ENCOUNTER_ID)
    public long encounterId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "JobTypeID")
    @JsonProperty(JobType.SQL_FIELD_JOB_TYPE_ID)
    public long JobTypeID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Stat")
    @JsonProperty(FIELD_STAT)
    public boolean IsStat;

    @ColumnInfo(name ="LocalFlags")
    @JsonIgnore
    public int localFlags;

    @Ignore
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean dirty;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "State")
    public int State;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "OwnerDictatorID")
    private long OwnerDictatorID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "QueueID")
    private long QueueID;

    @Ignore
    private Encounter encounter;

    @Ignore
    private CheckSums checkSums;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "AudioUploadState")
    @JsonIgnore
    public int audioUploadState;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ImagesUploadState")
    @JsonIgnore
    public int imagesUploadState;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "HasDictation")
    private boolean hasDictation;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "HasImages")
    private boolean hasImages;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "HasChatUpload")
    private boolean hasChatUpload;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "UpdatedDateInUTC")
    @JsonProperty(FIELD_UPDATED_DATE)
    private String updatedDateInUTC;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "MessageThreadID")
    private String messageThreadID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastsynctime")
    private String lastSyncTime;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "jobState")
    private int jobState;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "referringphysicianid")
    private long referringPhysicianId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "dictationtext")
    private String dictationText;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "macrosList")
    private String macrosList;


    @ColumnInfo(name = "jobstatusgroup")
    private int StatusGroupID;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "uploadeddate")
    private String UploadedDate;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "RhythmTagMetadata")
    private String tagMetadata;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "RhythmWorkFlowId")
    public long jobRhythmWorkFlowId = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "RhythmRecordedDuration")
    public long rhythmRecordingDetaion = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "IsRhythmJob")
    public boolean isRhythmJob = false;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "lastvisitedtagposition")
    public String lastVisitedTag = "";


    @ColumnInfo(name = "isSendToTranscriptionEnabled")
    private long isSendToTranscriptionEnabled;

    @Ignore
    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> tagSelection;

    //    public int background = 0;

    @Ignore
    public HashMap<String, Integer> tagscrollpositions;

    public Job() {
    }


}
```

I have getter setter method for above class.

Comment: I think update query will not return the `Job` user row. So change `writejob` method return type to `void` something like will help you..!

Comment: Welcome gald to help Happy coding :)